# Dropdown menu in navbar going up when scroll down

Tags: html, css

I have a simple dropdown menu in my navbar. the dropdown menu can appear by both hovering and clicking. when I hoover it the dropdown appears. when I clicked the dropdown button, the menu appears but in a different position and it going up when I scroll down. after 1 one day I still can't find the solution for this. can someone help me? I have put my code for your reference.

```css
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #0093E9;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(160deg, #0093E9 0%, #80D0C7 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(160deg, #0093E9 0%, #80D0C7 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(160deg, #0093E9 0%, #80D0C7 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, #0093E9 0%, #80D0C7 100%);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu-jk" class="container-fluid  no-padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 logo">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img class="log" src="assets/images/tesco-white.png" alt="" style="max-width: 100px;">
                        <img class="log-gray" src="assets/images/tesco-black.png" alt="" style="max-width: 100px;">
                    </a>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-head" href="index.html"><i class="fas d-block d-md-none small-menu fa-bars"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div id="nav-head" class="col-md-9 nav-div d-none d-md-block" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <ul id="nav" class="nav nav-pills clearfix right" role="tablist">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Company</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
                            <ul id="products-menu" class="dropdown-menu clearfix" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="">Communication</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Security</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Networking</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Cabling</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```